# Passing php variables through pages / sql

Tags: php, sql

i have the following information displayed

```
<?php
$my_query="SELECT * FROM games"; 
$result= mysqli_query($connection, $my_query);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
while ($myrow = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
$description = $myrow["game_description"];
$image = $myrow["gamepic"];
$game_id = $myrow["game_id"];
$gamename = $myrow["game_name"];
    echo "<div class='cover'>
    <a href='game_details.php?gameid={$game_id}'> <img src=\"games/$image\"       class=\"thumbnail\" width=\"200\" height=\"200\"> </a>
    </div>";
}   
?>
```

as you can see i have created a game_details page which will display that specific Game_id when the image is clicked

im having trouble understanding how to pull the data out from that game_id in sql on the other page.

here is my attempt on the game_details page

```
 <?php 
 if (!isset($_GET['$game_id']) || empty($_GET['game_id']))
{
echo "Invalid category ID.";
exit();
}

    $game_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_GET['game_id']);
     $sql1 = "SELECT * games WHERE game_id={$game_id}'"; 
     $res4 = mysqli_query($connection, $sql1);
 if(!$res4 || mysqli_num_rows($res4) <= 0)
    {

                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res4))
                {
                    $gameid = $row['$game_id'];
                    $title = $row['game_name'];
                    $descrip = $row['game_description'];
                    $genre = $row['genretype'];


                    echo "<p> {$title} </p>";

                }           
    }
?>
```

This attempt is giving me the "invalid category ID" error

Would appreciate help

Comment: `['$game_id']` you should remove the dollar sign from it in `$_GET['$game_id']` that explains the error.

Comment: same thing for `$row['$game_id']` - you also have a syntax error in `game_id={$game_id}'`

Comment: having this error
 Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\WT-NMP\WWW\final\game_details.php on line 21

that refers to this line 
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res4))
                {
                    $gameid = $row['$game_id'];


could you help me more?

Comment: you should also use proper bracing for all your conditional statements. this one has none `if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)` and will cause potential havoc.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few issues with your code.

*Let's start from the top.*

`['$game_id']` you need to remove the dollar sign from it in `$_GET['$game_id']`

Then, `$row['$game_id']` same thing; remove the dollar sign.

Then, `game_id={$game_id}'` will throw a syntax error.

In your first body of code; you should also use proper bracing for all your conditional statements.

This one has none `if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)` and will cause potential havoc.

Rewrites:

```
<?php
$my_query="SELECT * FROM games"; 
$result= mysqli_query($connection, $my_query);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
while ($myrow = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
$description = $myrow["game_description"];
$image = $myrow["gamepic"];
$game_id = $myrow["game_id"];
$gamename = $myrow["game_name"];
    echo "<div class='cover'>
    <a href='game_details.php?gameid={$game_id}'> <img src=\"games/$image\" class=\"thumbnail\" width=\"200\" height=\"200\"> </a>
    </div>";
}   

}
?>
```

Sidenote for `WHERE game_id='{$game_id}'` in below. If that doesn't work, remove the quotes from it.

`WHERE game_id={$game_id}`

2nd body:

```
<?php 
 if (!isset($_GET['game_id']) || empty($_GET['game_id']))
{
echo "Invalid category ID.";
exit();
}

    $game_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_GET['game_id']);
     $sql1 = "SELECT * games WHERE game_id='{$game_id}'"; 
     $res4 = mysqli_query($connection, $sql1);
 if(!$res4 || mysqli_num_rows($res4) <= 0)
    {

                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res4))
                {
                    $gameid = $row['game_id'];
                    $title = $row['game_name'];
                    $descrip = $row['game_description'];
                    $genre = $row['genretype'];


                    echo "<p> {$title} </p>";

                }       
    }
?>
```

---

**Use error checking tools at your disposal during testing:**

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Answer (score 0):

You want to be using $_GET['gameid'] as that's the parameter you passed.

Comment: Where would i be using that, im pretty much a beginner at this. would appreciate if you could elaborate

Comment: To be honest, rather than trying to explain the basics on SO, I'd suggest you read up on few tutorials before continuing writing PHP blind. 

gameid is the GET key you selected in your a tag on the first page. To access that on the requested page, you use $_GET['gameid'], not game_id, which is what your variable name was on the first page. As for why you use $game_id as an array key in places, I can't tell.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling for `game_id` when the link to go to `game_details.php` has the variable `gameid`. Either change the parameter in the link to `game_id` or call for `gameid` in your `$_GET['$game_id']`.

Also, as Fred -ii- said, take out the dollar sign in `$_GET['$game_id']`

Comment: i know the basics of PHP, im just having trouble implementing that with SQL. i have grabbed the ID from the $_get on the second page. i don't know how to search that $_GET in sql and then output it.